# Rees algebras: why do we have this bijection on minimal primes?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

I'm learning a little bit about Rees algebras lately, and I'm reading from Swanson and Huneke's *Integral Closure of Ideals, Rings, and Modules* (available [here](https://www.math.purdue.edu/%7Eiswanso/book/SwansonHuneke.pdf) on one of the author's websites) and there's one passage from the book that's just not making any sense to me.

First the authors define the Rees algebra and extended Rees algebra:

> **Definition 5.1.1.** Let $R$ be a ring, $I$ an ideal, and $t$ a variable over $R$. The **Rees algebra of $I$** is the subring of $R[t]$ defined as $$R[It]=\left\{ \sum_{i=0}^n a_it^i\mid n\in\Bbb N; a_i\in I^i\right\} = \bigoplus_{n\geq 0} I^nt^n,$$ and the **extended Rees algebra of $I$** is the subring of $R[t,t^{-1}]$ defined as $$R[It,t^{-1}]=\left\{ \sum_{i=-n}^n a_it^i\mid n\in\Bbb N; a_i\in I^i\right\} = \bigoplus_{n\in \Bbb Z} I^nt^n,$$ where by convention for any non-positive integer $n$, $I^n=R$.

Immediately after, they make the following observations:

> For every ideal $J$ of $R$, $$ J\subseteq JR[It]\cap R \subseteq JR[It,t^{-1}]\cap R \subseteq JR[t,t^{-1}]\cap R = J,$$ so that equality holds throughout. Thus every ideal of $R$ is contracted from an ideal of $R[It]$ and $R[It,t^{-1}]$. Also, $$\frac{R}{J} \subseteq \frac{R[It]}{JR[t,t^{-1}]\cap R[It]} \subseteq \frac{R[It,t^{-1}]}{JR[t,t^{-1}]\cap R[It]}\subseteq \frac{R[t,t^{-1}]}{JR[t,t^{-1}]},$$ where the two rings in the middle are isomorphic to the Rees algebra, respectively the extended Rees algebra, of the image of $I$ in $R/J$.

So far so good (or so I think). The next couple sentences lose me completely:

> In particular, if $P$ is a minimal prime ideal of $R$, then $PR[t,t^{-1}]\cap R[It]$ and $PR[t,t^{-1}]\cap R[It,t^{-1}]$ are minimal prime ideals in their respective rings. Any nilpotent element of $R[It]$ or $R[It,t^{-1}]$ is also nilpotent in $R[t,t^{-1}]$, so it lies in $\bigcap_P PR[t,t^{-1}]$ as $P$ varies over the minimal prime ideals of $R$. Thus all the minimal prime ideals of the two Rees algebras are contracted from the minimal prime ideals of $R[t,t^{-1}]$, each of which is of the form $PR[t,t^{-1}]$, for some minimal prime ideal $P$ of $R$.

The biggest immediate issue for me is that I do not see how to justify the claim about minimal primes. I see that the associations $J\mapsto JR[t,t^{-1}]\cap R[It]$ and $J\mapsto JR[t,t^{-1}]\cap R[It,t^{-1}]$ send prime ideals to prime ideals (the second centered line with the quotients shows that if $J$ is prime, the quotient of each ring by the respective associated ideal is a domain), and I see that they preserve containment (if $J\subset J'$, then $JR[t,t^{-1}]\subset J'R[t,t^{-1}]$, and so $JR[t,t^{-1}] \cap R[It] \subset J'R[t,t^{-1}]\cap R[It]$ and similarly for the extended Rees algebra). But I don't see how the text preceding this section shows that if $J$ is a minimal prime then $JR[t,t^{-1}]\cap R[It]$ and $JR[t,t^{-1}]\cap R[It,t^{-1}]$ are minimal primes, or how to fill this gap otherwise.

Can anyone help me understand this passage and why this statement about minimal primes is true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see how the text explicitly shows that $P$ minimal implies $PR[t,t^{-1}] \cap R[It]$ is a minimal prime, either.  But maybe Huneke and Swanson expect the reader to do a little bit of work from the most basic properties of minimal primes and their knowledge of $R[t,t^{-1}]$?

They probably expect that you know the following:

> **Fact 1** The minimal prime ideals of $R[t,t^{-1}]$ are precisely the ideals $PR[t,t^{-1}]$ for minimal primes $P$ of $R$.

> **Fact 2** If $P$ is a minimal prime of a ring $R$ and $R \subseteq S$ is an extension of rings, then $P$ is contracted from a (minimal) prime of $S$.

> **Corollary to Fact 2** If $R \subseteq T \subseteq S$ where the minimal primes of $S$ are extended from the minimal primes of $R$ and $PS \cap R =P$ for each minimal prime of $R$, then $PS \cap T$ is a minimal prime for each minimal prime $P$ of $R$.

**Proof** If $Q$ is a minimal prime of $T$ contained in $PS \cap T$, then Fact 2 implies that $Q = P'S \cap T$ for some minimal prime.  Then $Q = P'S \cap T \subseteq PS \cap T$ and contracting further to $R$ we find $P' \subseteq P$.  Since $P$ is minimal, conclude $P = P'$.  Therefore $Q = PS \cap T$ and $PS \capt T$ is a minimal prime of $T$.

Now from the first part of the text you quoted combined with Fact 1, the ring $S = R[t,t^{-1}]$ satisfies the hypotheses in the preceding corollary.  Hence for any ring $T$ intermediate between $R$ and $R[t,t^{-1}]$ (including any Rees algebra), the prime $PR[t,t^{-1}] \cap T$ are minimal for any minimal prime of $R$.